# Can we install Office 2013 on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows, ms-office, windows-server, office-2013

Hi can we install Office 2013 on Windows Server 2012?

I tried to find on many places but cannot find any example. Too tough to experiment myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, yes it will.

Source: I have the RC installed for 2012 and received a beta copy of 2013